# How to stub download from remote url in Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, carrierwave

I have a `User` AR model and when I save a `User` instance with a populated value of `remote_avatar_url`, Carrierwave automatically downloads the avatar. More info about this feature [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#uploading-files-from-a-remote-location).

Now, in my tests, I want to stub this behavior. I know I can do:

```
allow_any_instance_of(UserAvatarUploader).to receive(:download!)
```

however, the `rspec-mocks` documentation [discourages the use of `allow/expect_any_instance_of`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#settings-mocks-or-stubs-on-any-instance-of-a-class).

What is the proper way of stubbing this specific feature of Carrierwave in tests?

P.S. I have already disabled image processing in tests:

```
config.enable_processing = false if Rails.env.test?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, the answer is to use the [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) gem. It blocks outbound HTTP connections during testing and allows you to easily stub responses.

After setting up the gem per the instructions, I added this to my tests:

```
body_file = File.open(File.expand_path('./spec/fixtures/attachments/sample.jpg'))
stub_request(:get, 'www.thedomainofmyimage.example.net').
  to_return(body: body_file, status: 200)
```

Worked like a charm with CarrierWave's `remote_<uploader>_url` feature.